# How do I use an external lib from netbeans tar file when compiling from cmd with javac?

Tags: java, jar, import

Not sure if there is a simple solution, but I hope. I have searched and found complicated solutions writing code reading the tar lib. Is this really necessary? Since netbeans, intellij and eclipse can use external libraries, it must be possible to do that when compiling directly with javac as well?

If I unzip the tar-fil, and drop the classes in the correct file structure maps, no problem. But where is the magic from the ide:s?

the code I'm trying to "migrate" uses this line
getContentPane().add(button1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(90, 80, 70, 70));

the class is "hidden" in this lib AbsoluteLayout.jar
If I unzip the lib to org\netbeans\lib\awtextra in my src folder, it works, but should that really be neccessary?

isn't possible to import the lib like other packages are imported?

import org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.*?   or is the trick to add the AbsoluteLayout folder outside? Tried all combinations I can think of. Greatful for any hints.

Comment: is it possible to extract information from a jar, or do I need to unzip it first? is this what the ide's do? unzip the classes needed and repack them, or is there any easier way?

Comment: Found this, anyone tried it?
javac -classpath /myclasses/myclasses.jar  http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html
Can I try this with an external lib, and in that case, should the lib be placed on the same level as my Main class?